How to change the language or texts of the date and time picker buttons in a webview?
When I use the HTML input type time or date in an Android WebView, the translation for set and clear is missing in the date and time picker.
In this example, I am using Portuguese as the language. Example site used in the WebView and Chrome browser app: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time
In Flutter webview, the translation for set and clear is missing.


I am using the in_appweview plugin.
final InAppWebViewGroupOptions _webViewOptions = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
  useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: false,
  javaScriptEnabled: true,
  allowFileAccessFromFileURLs: true,
  allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs: true,
  javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true,
  supportZoom: false,
  userAgent:
      'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
),
ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
  allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
),
android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
  useHybridComposition: true,
  allowContentAccess: true,
  allowFileAccess: true,
),

);

Why aren't you using the official webview_flutter package?

I also tested with the webview_flutter package and had the same problem.

any idea @RandalSchwartz?
